# ¿Como llenar un dropdownlist con PHP?

Tags: php, array, formularios

Estuve creando un campo dropdownlist con los paises del mundo,pero habia algo que me incomodaba ya que lo estaba haciendo mediante HTML y cualquier usuario puede modificar el codigo HTML  a traves de la herramienta de desarrollo del navegador.

Mi pregunta es ¿como lo hago con PHP.?Osea desde una BD o desde un archivo php.He visto que lo hacen mediante un array con los paises,pero no esta completo ya que no muestran el procedimiento para llenar el dropdownlist.

Comment: me he perdido algo... con el PHP acabas generando un documento HTML que va al navegador del usuario, y obviamente podrá modificarlo... pero sólo podrá modificar la copia que tiene en su navegador. La diferencia de rellenar el select de una forma o de otra dependerá normalmente de si el contenido es estático o dinámico.

Comment: entonces como se podria resolver eso?

Comment: es que no hay problema que resolver. El cliente siempre puede hacer lo que quiera con el HTML (o cualquier otra cosa que se ejecute en su máquina). Si tienes que aseguarte que no te pasa información incorrecta, lo tienes que hacer al procesar la respuesta es verificarla.

Comment: @SJuan76 Entonces no hay problema dejarlo asi.?Si el usuario,por ejemplo donde dice   <option value="AR">Argentina</option>,le da el placer de escribir jhhcjjkchscsduihwhu y presiona el boton enviar asi mismo se ira.

Comment: La solución es que en el código que reciba los datos del formulario validar que la entrada sea de uno de los valores de la lista y no jhhcjjkchscsduihwhu, y si hay datos incorrectos no procesar la petición. Lo dicho, **NUNCA** puedes confiar en los datos que te envía un cliente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante ajax podes llenar tu listado de países. Ejemplo con JQuery:
Lado del cliente (navegador web)

```
<script>
function getPaises(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_state.php",
        data:'pais_id=' + val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#listado_paises").html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Lado del servidor creas un archivo llamado get_state.php que obtenés el listado de tus países.

Ahí resolvés con el listado, pero no te salvas que el usuario modifique el valor que te manda. La única solución es crear una función de verificación de datos válidos, antes de guardar en la base  de datos. 
Independientemente al crear el listado de países de forma dinámica o estática, siempre te conviene hacer una verificación. Podes hacerlo desde el cliente (navegador web) y en el servidor. Lo que si o si tenes que hacer, es en el lado del servidor que es el mas importante.

Comment: Amigo creo que lo voy a dejar como lo tenia,pero tengo otro poblemita y es que cuando inserto en la BD me guarda la bareviatura de los paises en vez de los nombre.

Comment: Eso es por tu name o id de tu combobox. Ahy deberías de poner el nombre de tu país

Comment: @luis si se soluciono el problema, podrias poner como solucionado. Gracias